# How do I search for the last 5 years in a Mongodb collection using Dates for Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDb orders collection that has a field called order_date which indicates the year a customer made a purchase. I want to be able to query for a customer's orders up to 5 years ago. The collection fields look like below

```
     
    customer_id: '12345',
    transaction_id: 'TXN-0999999',
    order_date: '2022-09-13T13:30:00.000+00:00'
    shipping_street: 'Pike Street',
    shipping_house_num: '1121',
    shipping_city: 'Albany',
    shipping_state: 'New York',
    ...
```

I want to write a Mongodb query where the orderDate in years not greater than 5 years. I tried this  but I got no results: I am using Mongoose but the ISODate is flagged as an error. How do I replace the ISODate for Mongoose to work?

{order_date:{$gte:ISODate("2020-10-19T20:26:27.264Z"),$lt:ISODate("2018-10-19T20:31:19.708Z")}}